# Migrate Global.asax to Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

For better test job with `Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer`, I found that Global.asax is not loaded with Owin TestServer.

So, I try to move my Global.asax configurations to Startup.cs as below,

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // pasted Global.asax things start.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();

        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        };
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = jsonSerializerSettings });
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        // pasted Global.asax things end.

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

But `TestServer` **failed** to initialize in every point of configuration such as `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas`, `FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)`, so on...

Minimum viable migration(successful test with TestServer) for me is as below.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Formatters.Clear();

        var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        };
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = jsonSerializerSettings });
        config.Formatters.Add(new FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());

        WebApiConfig.Register(config); // moved from GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)
        app.UseWebApi(config);
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to move all configurations to Startup.cs?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As you are already aware, `OwinContext` consumed by `Startup.Configuration()` is different from the traditional ASP.NET `HttpContext` consumed by `MvcApplication.Application_Start()`. Both are using different context pipelines. More specifically, ASP.NET MVC still relies on `System.Web.dll` while ASP.NET Web API doesn't.

Therefore, based on your code, some methods usually laid in `MvcApplication.Application_Start()` can't be run within `Startup.Configuration()`:

- `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`: This method relies on `System.Web.dll`.
- `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`: `RouteCollection` is a part of `System.Web.dll`.
- `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)`: Again, `RouteCollection` within `WebApiConfig.Register()` is a part of `System.Web.dll`.

For URL routing within OWIN context, `AttributeRouting` is recommended. So, instead of this, try `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` That will give you much freedom.

If you still want to run `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` within OWIN context, `Startup.Configuration()`, I'd better recommend to import [Katana library](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb). This integrates OWIN with `System.Web.dll` so that you probably archieve your goal.

HTH

Comment: So do we just install the package and job done or anything else have to be done ?

Comment: @Gurpreet Indeed. If you install at least [Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/) and move bits and pieces from `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs` to `Startup.cs`, it should be fine.