# how to migrate global.asax event 'Application_Start' to program.cs on net.6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, middleware, .net-6.0

I try to migrate an old projet with a console app and a webservice ( both on .net framework 4.6) to a .net 6 console app (I want to suppress the ws and just have a service).
On the old webservice I have a global.asax with a usefull event 'Application_Start' : it let me initialise a static class used for data access (code is in vb.net but I move to c#)

```
  Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        OldDLL.Initialisation(BmyEnum.Mode, My.Settings.mySCHEMAName)
    End Sub
```

I find various topics as ([Migrate Global.asax to Startup.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032284/migrate-global-asax-to-startup-cs)) on how to migrate from global.asax to Startup.cs
but there is no more Startup.cs on my project generate by visualstudio2022, just a program.cs.
Googleling a little bit I read that program.cs could replace startup.cs, using middleware.
But I'm very new and it's a lot confusing. How I could in a simple way call OldDLL.Initialisation on program.cs ? Could be possible ( and how?)  to embed my OldDll static on a service and inject it ? Thank you for reading, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you going to be hosting anything other than the console app? If it just going to be a console app you may not need startup.

Answer (score 0):

in fact my projet is a vs2022 ASP.net core with react js projet.
I found how to do:
I create a service class to embed my dll:

```
public class OldDLLService:IOldDllService
{
    public OldDllService()
    {
        oldDLL.Initialisation();
    }
    
    public void DoSome()
    {
    //..
    }
}
```

And the interface playing with :

```
public interface IOldDllService
{
    void DoSome();
}
```

On programm.cs I injected the service :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IOldDllService, OldDllService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

And after can easy use for example in a controller:

```
public DummyController(ILogger<DummyController> logger, IOldDllService oldDllService)
{
 _logger = logger;
_oldDllService = oldDllService;

public void doSome()
{
 _oldDllService.DoSome();
}}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question you asked. It's not needed either. `Program.cs` *is* the application start code. What you posted shows how to register a service so it can be used by other classes. You don't need to do that to use an external DLL though, you could use a simple static class. Using it as a singleton makes testing easier but isn't always worth the extra complexity

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I naively thought it answered my question, and then it allows me to do what I was doing initially with the global.asax.. but if you say it I believe you.. the main thing is that it works..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is true that I put a lot of coating perhaps not useful, maybe simply that I did not know how make a static class and call its initialization method once at startup.